# Implementing MS-Active Directory role based access control (authorization) for sensitive financial data

Tags: active-directory, authorization, roles

We are developing a java web app for our client and they asked these two questions:

1. Can you include integration with MS-AD for single-sign-on as part of scope of implementation (for user authentication) ?
2. There should be some write-up on how the Authorization mechanism will work within the solution and how access to confidential financial information is protected. Usually SAP has a rigorous role-based authorization approach. But, as this solution is outside SAP, how the user-authorization will be implemented?

I need to reply so please suggest me what should I write back to them as I don't know much about MS technologies.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Authentication

Active Directory can be used as source of SIngle Sign on X.509 or Kerberos tickets.  SAP can accept those tickets.

- Authorization

Microsoft has a tool Forefront Identity Manager which has [SAP connector Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863241%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
This can update the Roles allocated to users directly.